# An app that sends an alarm to family in case of an abnormal heart rate

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

I bought an apple watch just for this reason (Yeah I should have done my research beforehand). But I wanted to monitor her heart rate after she recently had a stroke.
Is there an app that can send an alarm to my IPhone in case here heart rate exceeds a certain bpm or any other criteria? I know apple itself doesn't support a function like this because they don't want their device being used as a medical device, but that's exactly what I would like it to be.